# SOLID - Principio de Responsabilidad Unica (SRP), aplicado a funciones de una clase o toda la clase?

Tags: patrones-de-diseño, ingenieria-del-software

Tengo dudas con el principio de responsabilidad única (SRP).

Como dice "Cada objeto en el sistema deben tener una simple responsabilidad, y todos los servicios de los objetos deben cumplir con esa simple responsabilidad".

Lo que no entiendo es ¿Debo aplicar este principio a cada función dentro de una clase? o es que ¿cada clase debe ser responsable de una sola cosa? Lo que me hace ruido es: Si la clase tiene una sola responsabilidad significaría que tendría una, dos o bien muy pocas funciones y no se si eso esta bien.

Comment: Aunque la pregunta es super interesante, desafortunadamente las posibles respuestas estarán basadas en opiniones, razón por la cual será potencialmente cerrada. Te recomendaría revisar [ask] para que veas cómo deberíamos preguntar. Sería mejor [edit] la pregunta y hacerla mucho más específica.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente debes aplicar ese principio siempre que puedas sin olvidar su naturaleza intrínseca, precisamente es un principio, no una regla.

Muchas veces es conveniente por ejemplo separar la creación de los componentes gráficos de la construcción de un objeto cuando haces swing, otras veces poner la creación de un objeto con un builder para evitar estados inconsistentes en la creación de objetos, otras veces harás capas de base de datos y dentro de ellos métodos para cada una de las operaciones CRUD.

Cuando usarlo depende de tí, basicamente la respuesta correcta a eso sería cuando te haga sentido y te sea ventajoso.

La idea detrás de ese principio es **software mantenible**.